# Swift async/await in a for loop or map

Tags: swift, for-loop, async-await, concurrency

I have this model:

```
struct ExactLocation {
    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        get async throws {
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            let placemark = try await geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address)
            let mark = MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark.first!)
            return mark.coordinate
        }
    }
}
struct Property {
    let exactLocation: ExactLocation?
}
```

I am trying to loop over an array of `Property` to fetch all the coordinates using Swift 5.5 async/await.

```
private func addAnnotations(for properties: [Property]) async {
    let exactLocations = try? properties.compactMap { try $0.exactLocation?.coordinates } <-- Error: 'async' property access in a function that does not support concurrency

    let annotations = await properties.compactMap { property -> MKPointAnnotation? in
        if let exactLocation = property.exactLocation {
            if let coordinates = try? await exactLocation.coordinates {
                
            }
        }
    } <-- Error: Cannot pass function of type '(Property) async -> MKPointAnnotation?' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

    properties.forEach({ property in
        if let exactLocation = property.exactLocation {
            if let coordinates = try? await exactLocation.coordinates {
                
            }
        }
    } <-- Error: Cannot pass function of type '(Property) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
}
```

So how can I iterate over this array with an async function?
Do I need to create an `AsyncIterator`? The docs are quite confusing on this, how would I do this for this simple example?

Comment: So you just want to compact map `[Property]` to `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]`? I'm guessing what you have shown is 3 of your attempts to solve the same problem (and not 3 separate problems)?

Comment: Yes. I've shows 3 different attempts and the errors they give. Because my `coordinates` var is async due to `geocodeAddressString` being async. I want to get an array of coordinates to then place as map annotations.

Comment: I'm not sure why an answer was deleted, but luckily I managed to screen grab it before I had to go out and it was deleted as it does in fact do the job.

Comment: I deleted it because I had made some assumptions about your situation that are probably incorrect. You probably want the mapped coordinates to be in the same order as the properties, right? Using a `TaskGroup` wouldn't guarantee that order. I was not paying attention to the general context of what you are doing (adding annotations) and didn't consider the order as important.

Comment: Ah yes. I quickly realised I needed these linked/members of the `Property` itself to use it's other properties. I think I may need to look at having the `Property` compute the coordinates on `init()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be careful about the number of requests that you perform. The [docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder):

> - Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.
> - If the user performs multiple actions that involve geocoding the same location, reuse the results from the initial geocoding request instead of starting individual requests for each action.
> - When you want to update the user’s current location automatically (such as when the user is moving), issue new geocoding requests only when the user has moved a significant distance and after a reasonable amount of time has passed. For example, in a typical situation, you should not send more than one geocoding request per minute.

And the old [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1) says:

> The same `CLGeocoder` object can be used to initiate any number of geocoding requests but only one request at a time may be active for a given geocoder.

So, the whole idea of rapidly issuing a series of geolocation requests may be imprudent, and even if you were to do just a few, I would be inclined to avoid performing them concurrently. So, I would consider a simple `for` loop, e.g.:

```swift
func addAnnotations(for addresses: [String]) async throws {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    
    for address in addresses {
        if 
            let placemark = try await geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address).first,
            let coordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate
        {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = placemark.name
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            
            // ...
            
            // you might even want to throttle your requests, e.g.
            //
            // try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: nanoseconds) 
        }
    }
}
```

---

Technically, you could do the computed property approach. Now, I did not see `address` in your model anywhere, but let’s imagine:

```swift
struct Property {
    let address: String
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        get async throws {
            try await CLGeocoder()
                .geocodeAddressString(address)
                .first?.location?.coordinate
        }
    }
}
```

(Note the elimination of the forced unwrapping operator and the unnecessary instantiating of another placemark.)

Then you could do:

```swift
func addAnnotations(for properties: [Property]) async throws {
    for property in properties {
        if let coordinate = try await property.coordinate {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I am not crazy about that approach (as we are hiding rate-limited `CLGeocoder` requests with all sorts of constraints inside a computed property; if you access the same property repeatedly, duplicate geocoder requests will be issued, which Apple explicitly advises that we avoid). But the `async` property technically works, too.

---

Often when dealing with annotations, we want to be able to interact with the annotation views on our map and know with which model object they are associated. For that reason, we would often keep some sort of cross reference between our annotations and our model objects.

If `Property` was a reference type, we might use a `MKPointAnnotation` subclass that kept a reference to the appropriate `Property`. Or we might just make our `Property` conform to `MKAnnotation`, itself, eliminating the need for references between annotations and separate model objects. There are lots of ways to tackle this requirement, and I’m not sure we have enough information to advise you on the correct pattern in your case.

Comment: Thank you for this. So many useful things i've taken away from it. Regarding my loop `for x in xx` as you suggest works fine whereas the `xx.forEach` I was using does not, so that was an easy fix. I will add some caching to make sure the geocoding isn't performed once it's already successfully returned.

Comment: I also hadn't considered making my `Property` conform to `MKAnnotation` itself and had implemented a subclass to do the work. Thx